# caculating the avarage from a list<String>

Tags: list, flutter

suppose i have a list containing emojies:

```
List<String> _emojiesList = ['☹️','','','','',''];
```

let's say 6 people reviewed and selected an emoji from that list:

```
person 1 - ☹️
person 2 - 
person 3 - 
person 4 - ☹️
person 5 - ☹️
person 6 -
```

**im trying to display the avarage of those emojies.**

i do know how to calculate the avarage:

avg = **indexOfEmoji***numberOfSelected / totalNumberOfPeople

```
so: 
☹️ - 3 
 - 2
 - 1
```

(0 * 3 + 1 * 2 + 2 * 1) / 6 = 4/6 = 0.667.round() = 1

the problem is that the first emoji has been muntiplyed with **index of 0**.

it seems that can't find a way to solve this issue. I just need to print just the avarage.

Comment: I don't think the index needs to be part of the average, maybe instead have a list of averages so indexes line up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the user reviewed.. add **index** of the clicked emoji to a list.

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5] // The list will look something like this
```

And then to calculate Average

```
var avg = ( reviewedList.reduce((a, b) => a + b) / reviewedList.length ).round();
print(_emojiesList[avg]);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that all 6 emojis have weights (or points) from 1 to 6.

In that case, you can increase the array index number by 1 while calculating the averages:

```
avg = (indexOfEmoji+1)*numberOfSelected / totalNumberOfPeople
```

In that case, you'll get,

```
(1 * 3 + 2 * 2 + 3 * 1) / 6 = 4/6 = 1.667
```

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter that the first emoji is multiplied by 0. Nevertheless, the correct result comes out, i.e. the average of the indices. It should fit that way.

If you want the first emoji to have weight 1, then all you have to do is increase the final score by 1.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @deeperm comment.

However, if you really want to do this, just offset indices by 1.

```
List<int> _emojiesNumbers = [1, 2, 4, 3, 5, 8];

void main() {
  var avg = 0.0;
  var idxByEmojies = 0;
  var nbEmojies = 0;
  _emojiesNumbers.asMap().forEach((index, value) {
    idxByEmojies += (index+1)*value;
    nbEmojies += value;
  });

  avg = idxByEmojies/nbEmojies;

  print(avg);
}
```